# How can I export an array from one component to App.js in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I've been trying to use array "components" in App.js, while the array is initialized in Sidebar.jsx component.
**Sidebar.jsx :**

```
import ...
const Sidebar = () => {
 ...
  const apps = [
    // name - kako se zove na sidebaru, icon-icon, jsx - ime componente bez .jsx
    { name: 'To Do App', icon: FaTasks, jsx: 'ToDo' },
    { name: 'Weather', icon: TiWeatherPartlySunny, jsx: 'Card' },
    { name: 'Finance Tracker', icon: FaMoneyBill, jsx: 'Tracker' },
    { name: 'Metronome', icon: BsFileEarmarkMusicFill, jsx: 'Metronome' },
  ];
   const components = apps.map((app)=>(app.jsx))
  
  return (
    <>
 <AppContext.Provider value={components}>
    
      ...
      {isOpen && (
        <div className='h-screen w-[310px] bg-white bg-opacity-90 top-0 right-0 fixed'>
          <div className='flex flex-row gap-3 my-7'>
            <RxAllSides className='text-4xl font-bold' />
            <h1 className='text-3xl'>All in One App</h1>
          </div>

          <div className='w-full flex-col justify-start align-start'>
            <h2 className='opacity-75 text-2xl py-5 ml-4'>APPS</h2>
            <div className='flex flex-col gap-7 mt-3'>
              {apps.map((app) => (
                <div
                  key={app.name}
                  className='flex w-full h-8 flex-row justify-between align-middle opacity-60 cursor-pointer relative hover:opacity-90 hover:scale-105 hover:transition-transform'
                  onClick={(e) => handleRender(e)}
                >
                  <app.icon className='text-3xl absolute top-[-4px] mr-2 left-9' />
                  <h2 className='text-2xl absolute left-[6.3rem]'>{app.name}</h2>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </AppContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

export default Sidebar;
And **App.js:**

```
import { AppContext } from './appContext';
...
function App() {
  
  const { components } = useContext(AppContext);
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className='text-black text-8xl text-center p-8 fancy-font '>All in One App</h1>
      <div className='App flex flex-row gap-[20px] flex-wrap relative'>
    
        {components.map((Comp, index) => (
            <Comp key={index} />
          ))}         
        <Sidebar/>

      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've tried to directly export it but it didn't work. Now I'm trying to get it to work with useContext hook but I get an error saying components is not defined so I cant map through it. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired work without using useContext. You just need to pass a variable as prop in sidebar.js from App.js and retrieve the content array as function in App.js.

Here is how to do this.

**SIDEBAR**

```
const sidebar =({handleComponents})=>{

 const apps = [
    { name: 'To Do App', icon: FaTasks, jsx: 'ToDo' },
    { name: 'Weather', icon: TiWeatherPartlySunny, jsx: 'Card' },
    { name: 'Finance Tracker', icon: FaMoneyBill, jsx: 'Tracker' },
    { name: 'Metronome', icon: BsFileEarmarkMusicFill, jsx: 'Metronome' },
  ];

handleComponents(apps)


//rest of code will be same
}
```

**APP**

```
import sidebar from 'path/to/sidebar';
const App =()=>{

return (
//rest of code is same

<Sidebar  handleComponents={(apps)=>{console.log(apps)
//access the components here and use accordingly

}} />
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

For context API to work, you need to have the component in which useContext is used as child (or child of child—any depth) of a context provider.

For export to work, you need to export it outside any function.

```
import ...

export yourArray = [...]

// your component 
function YourComponent() {
...
}
```

Best way is to create constants in a separate file.

However, it seems that for some reason, you are initializing the array inside of a component. In that case, you need to use global stores that do not require wrapping components inside provider.

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this

```
export const apps = [
{ name: 'To Do App', icon: FaTasks, jsx: 'ToDo' },
{ name: 'Weather', icon: TiWeatherPartlySunny, jsx: 'Card' },
{ name: 'Finance Tracker', icon: FaMoneyBill, jsx: 'Tracker' },
{ name: 'Metronome', icon: BsFileEarmarkMusicFill, jsx: 'Metronome' },
];
and import it in apps like
import { apps } from './Sidebar';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).